# How do I resolve error message "no module named websocket"

Tags: python, python-2.7, websocket

I have python 2.7

Then did: pip install websocket-client. Successful

In code have: import websocket

Now running code get error:  No module named websocket.

Already search for other issues, which did not solve it.

I am not sure if websocket is part of package websocket or of package websocket-client.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Seen this before I post this question. Did not resolved. I am not sure if websocket is part of package websocket or of package websocket-client. Anyway: Your comment didnt help

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/websocket_client/. `import websocket` is correct.

Comment: So any idea why I get the error when I installed obviously the right package?

Comment: There's plenty of articles online about import errors. Are you in the right environment when running your script?

Comment: The script is around 5000 lines with a lot of imports. There are already some websockets inside from packages autobahn.  I know there is python 2.7.x and that websocket-client is installed by pip install websocket-client. So here would be good to know how I can find out if the environment is right or not

Comment: Just type `python` in a terminal and then `import websocket` and see if you get the error. Also is websocket listed when you type just `pip list`

Comment: Thank you for your help. When I type pip list I see websocket-client in the list. When I type python and then import websocket, there is no error, just the next line appears.

Comment: How are you running your script? Sounds like you have everything installed fine and is working

Comment: After a research its possible that there is no underline__init__underline_.py on the correct places/directories?

Comment: Unlikely as you are importing a 3rd party module `import websocket` will work regardless unless you have named any of your files or folders `websocket` too.

Comment: Still same error. Tried to install over -r requirments.txt, which was working succesfully. But by running script, still have ImportError. aswell pip install --user did not helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to resolve it.

I had to install it by venv/bin/pip install instead of pip install

Answer (score 0):

I had to install it by "python setup.py install" install of  "pip install websocket-client" ,it's successful